# 2D array problem

Tags: c, arrays

I need to make one 2D array in  which one column store the pointer of some structure & another column store one 32 bit magic number.
how can i do it in 2D array.?
or any other method to keep track of this two columns info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
// The struct that will hold the pointer and the magic number
struct data {
    void *other_struct_ptr;
    unsigned int magic_number;
};

// Declare my array
struct data array[N];
```

Where N is the size of your array. Now just fill your data into the array. For example:

```
array[0].other_struct_ptr = NULL; // I used NULL for simplicity
array[0].magic_number = 0xDEADC0DE;
array[1].other_struct_ptr = NULL;
array[1].magic_number = 0xCAFEBABE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a struct like this:

```
struct data_t
{
    void *pointer;
    int magic_number;
};
```

Then use following array:

```
data_t values[100]; //100 is just for example
```

Or maybe you need such 2D array:

```
data_t values[100][100]; //100s are just for example
```